# When to drop AD and BC from dates?

Tags: writing-style, history, time

I see some texts using AD and BC or BCE and CE. But other texts just have the date, like 1992 and it is understood. Is there a rule of thumb for when to add these prefixes? I'm using Chicago-Turabian.

Comment: The words "AD" and "BC" are dropped or not dropped following the exact same rule that you follow for dropping or not dropping any other word.

Comment: We should prefix BCE dates with "-" and, when appropriate, CE dates with "+".  You can be first.

Comment: I'm not certain you would ever drop the BC/BCE when talking about a specific date.

Answer (score 3):

> **When to drop AD and BC from dates?**

Well as usual the answer is can the reader understand the text if you drop them. If you were talking about the G20 meeting in 2018 I think the meaning is clear even if you do not use A.D.
If you were talking about the evolution of military tactics used by Roman Centurions, then I am sure you would need to include B.C. or A.D.

Comment: Not only that but if you use a date without a subscript or any other indication from context that you are talking about BC (or BCE if you prefer) then most people will assume that you mean AD (or CE if you prefer). This means that AD and CE are used very infrequently except when discussing history or ancient buildings or artifacts.

Comment: @BoldBen Totally agree, however there are some exceptions. For example if you were talking about Neolithic farmers or the last ice age. So it is the relative context that defines if you can or cannot use them.

Comment: I agree about the farmers and the ice age but then the context provides the indication that we are talking about the BCE era as we both said. Also in those cases we would be talking about very large numbers in the past tense so the era would be clear from that as well.